# Python float point precision

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I am confused by the floating-point precision problem in python.

for example:
48.91 multiplies 10000:

```
> 48.91 * 10000
489099.9999999999994
```

I lose the precision, but if I directly type in 48.91 as float, it can perfectly represent it.

```
> 48.91
48.91

> float(48.91)
48.91
```

So how come sometimes It can keep the precision while sometimes It can't?? How to deal with this situation??

Comment: "but if I directly type in 48.91 as float, it can perfectly represent it" - no it can't. It's just hiding the imprecision.

Comment: Oh, got it.  that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read these articles

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

https://blog.tecladocode.com/decimal-vs-float-in-python/

TLDR;

Try to use decimal to handle this case

```
from decimal import Decimal

num = Decimal('48.91')
print(num * 10000)
```